# gradle & Idea auto import: Project resolve error

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

I create a simple gradle project:

**build.gradle:**

```
plugins {
    id 'idea'
    id 'java'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.apache.thrift:libthrift:0.9.3"
}

task taskTest {
    println "Hello world"
}
```

I run the command `gradle idea` and was open project in the Idea IDE. Idea offered me an *Import Gradle project*, I allow her this with "Use auto-import option".
In "Message Gradle sync" window I see the next warnings:

Warning:***root project 'test': Unable to resolve additional project configuration.**
Details: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: id for class: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.DefaultResolvedArtifact
Possible solutions: file*

Warning:***root project 'test': Unable to resolve additional project configuration.**
Details: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: id for class: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.DefaultResolvedArtifact
Possible solutions: file*

What I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really sure, but it seems, that your your Gradle version does not yet support the plugins DSL. You can avoid using it, just remove this:

```
plugins {
    id 'idea'
    id 'java'
}
```

and apply this plugins this way:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
```

Or you can try to update you Gradle version.

Comment: Hm, yes, it's resolves the problem. But, why this solution is works? I use gradle of 2.5 version (and gradlew 2.5 version too), in this version must support new plugins DSL. What's wrong?

Comment: Can you chech, may be you IDE by default uses another gradle version?

Comment: IDE uses gradle from gradle_home, which have a 2.5 version. But, I noticed that if I set a `version` of plugin - warnings will go away. Is `version` mandatory attribute? And how I can find out version of *java* plugin? In [his](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html) page this information is absent

Comment: this is what I [found](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugins_block). In this page describes an applying plugins with the plugins DSL: `...To apply a core plugin, the short name can be used...` I not understand, what I doing wrong...

Comment: @KirillDjonua never heard that version is mandatory. And don't even know, how to find a java plugin version.. That's odd. But this is the reason not to use plugin DSL while it's incubating and you are free to use a plain old way to apply plugins

Answer (score 1):

I also face this problem. It may be due to using new gradle version with old IntelliJ IDE. I just upgrade IntelliJ with latest version and problem disappear.